# 'Symbol's value as variable is void:' when using parameter on defun inside lambda

Tags: variables, debugging, emacs, quote, backquote

I would like to make this function to set keybind more shorter.

```
(defun defkey-arg2 ()
  (exwm-input-set-key (kbd "s-g")
                      (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (start-process-shell-command gkamus nil gkamus))))
```

then I write the shorter function with 2 parameters (the keybind and the app name)

```
(defun defkey-arg2 (key command) (...)
```

When I try the key as parameter, it will work

```
(defun defkey-arg2 (key)
  (exwm-input-set-key (kbd key)
                      (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (start-process-shell-command gkamus nil gkamus))))

(defkey-arg2 "s-g")
```

But, when I try write function like this

```
(defun defkey-arg2 (key command)
```

or

```
(defun defkey-arg2 (command)
  (exwm-input-set-key (kbd "s-g")
                      (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (start-process-shell-command command nil command)))

(defkey-arg2 "gkamus")
```

it raises error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void:' when using parameter on defun
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but I don't have time to look for it.

Comment: I always try to find one before ask question.
may be the duplicate have title that not explain the problem well.

Comment: Right. Sometimes it's tricky. And in the case of this error message there are multiple possible causes. Anyway, thanks for checking first - that helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of `lambda` isn't evaluated.  Using a backquote, the value of `command` can be substituted into the resulting expression.

```
(defun defkey-arg2 (command)
  (define-key (current-local-map)
    (kbd "s-g")
    `(lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (start-process-shell-command ,command nil ,command))))
```